# Click icon to view word or excel in browser

Tags: php

I create icons so when click can view the file in the browser in pdf working file
but in excel and word and ppt when click will not view  the file in the browser it will downlaod file
i dont know why ?

can you help so when file excel and word and ppt and user click icon will view the file iin the browser?

```
 <a href="upload/<?php echo $row['File']; ?>" target="_blank" title="View File"><button class="btn btn-datatable btn-icon btn-transparent-dark mr-2"><i data-feather="eye"></i></button></a>
```

Comment: Browsers does not contain Word/Excel/PowerPoint reader.

The solution can be - upload to google drive / one drive. Again it is not browser doing the magic but the onedrive/google drive converting the doc/xls/ppt into html content and then using js to support the various functionalities.

Comment: okay brother thank you for this information